How to use FiberSCIP, and how to implement it through Python's PuLP libraray?
I am already using SCIP as a solver for my optimization problem and I would like to use fscip for multithread calculations. I have downloaded and built the scip-9.2.0 on my linux machine and can use it right now, but I couldn't find any documentation regarding how to use fscip.
When I configure, if I can configure, fscip I am not sure that whether it is going to have it's seperate path for me to give to PuLP or it is going to be just another configuration item in scip.

I asked around, and this is what I got:
Regarding "it is going to have its separate path for me to give to PuLP or it is going to be just another configuration item in scip", it is the first one: fiberscip is a separate executable (there is no library, I would say), the command line arguments are a bit different than for the scip executable, there is no fiberscip shell that they could use in batch mode, and also the log output is different. So if PuLP calls SCIP via the executable, then they would need to adjust the way how the executable is run and how the output is processed.

First of all thank you for your answer! You mentioned that fiberscip is a separate executable, unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation or link to download any source file or whatsoever,  on SCIP website and other sources. Do you have any info on that as well?

@newbiee, when you build FiberSCIP it creates an executable, I think that's what it means. You can FiberSCIP here

Thank you J.Dionisio! My mistake was to setup scip only and not the sciopt optimization suite. When I did, it worked like a charm!

@J.Dionisio, is it possible to use FiberSCIP as well as SCIP e.g. in Pyomo or PySCIPOpt? If so, could you please, how to do that?

@A.Omidi On PySCIPOPt I know it's not, and I believe that's also the case in Pyomo.

@J.Dionisio, thanks for pointing this out.
